# How to add content using the link .append jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, append

Sample code

```
<div class='credit'>
Copy <a href="http://blabla.com">blabla</a>
</div>
```

in the code above I will add content and links

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.credit').append(' credit by <a href="http://www.blabladot.com">blabladot</a>');
});
```

but I tried and did not work, how the code is correct?

Comment: This should work, are you sure jQuery is loaded in your page?

Comment: Did you get an error or did it fail silently?

Comment: Yes, I've included jQuery. Before I ask I've tried it in jsfiddle, but when I apply on blogspot template does not work well.
Is the code wrong or does not work at blogspot template?

Comment: Where did you put the JQuery? Before or after the code above? You must include the JQuery before declare the function. Or, if it still doesn't work, try adding the `<span>` tags around the text like this: `$('.credit').append('<span> credit by <a href="http://www.blabladot.com">blabladot</a></span>');` -- If it still doesn't work, I'm sure the problem cames from the bracket that's not closed properly or something. Try to check the error code with Firebug or Chrome Inspector. (Press **CTRL + Shift + k** or **CTRL + Shift + i**, then reload the page).

Answer (score 0):

You have forgotten to include **jQuery**

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

[Working jsFiddle here.](http://jsfiddle.net/nbbAY/)

If you are using it in a blogger template, check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10319728/loading-jquery-in-a-blogger-post-causes-it-to-freeze). I would recommend you to take a look in your developer console (in chrome) or firebug (in firefox) for any javascript errors and mention them in the question.

Comment: They want you to post the details here, not just a link to a fiddle.

Comment: @Barmar: oh. I get it. Hadn't seen this in SO. But its irritating in this kind of cases, where the answer suffices in a single line. I had to write to lines extra to include the link to the fiddle in my answer :/

Comment: I've included jQuery

.../jquery-1.7.2.min.js

Before I ask I've tried it in jsfiddle, but when I apply on blogspot template does not work well.

Is the code wrong or does not work at blogspot template?

Comment: when i tried only with text only it works, but when adding a link does not work.

Comment: @SodiycKurniawan: maybe blogger does not allow adding of links via jquery, though not sure about it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure you add the latest version of jQuery library in your HTML's `<head></head>` section as follow:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Also, make sure that other jQuery files or scripts are included after the above link.

[Working fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/VTw6J/)